# cakephp REST problem

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

** SOLUTION **

I am using cakephp 1.3. I did not have to add any routes. All i did is after adding the action to the controller, I went to the url 
/controller/action/id
in my case it was
/test/bravo/123

and that did the trick

** End **

I am using cakephp 1.3 and I am trying to add webservice. I heard its very easy to add restful. What I want to do is to have one of the actions in my controller provoked and log into a logfile as a success. Lets say

```
function bravo(){ $this->log("success", "Testlog");
```

So far I went through documentation and added the following to my routes.php

Router::mapResources('tests');
Router::parseExtensions();

then in test controller I have this

```
<?php
class TestsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Tests';
    var $components = array('RequestHandler');

 .....
.....

function bravo(){

        $this->log("success", "Testlog");
    }   

?>
```

Now when I go to

```
/tests.bravo
```

, its not logging the success in the log file. What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: ah found the solution. I will add to my question

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and accept it. You may even get the [Self-Learner](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) badge if others find it useful.